# TFS Branching / Versioning Basics

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I am very new to TFS. I have below Structure where I have my entire SOLUTION checked into my TFS online Repository.

[image]

Now, we are done with this Feature/Version.

What we want to do is...Leave this version AS IS and create a new Version / Branch out of this. This way if we ever have to go back to this version we can easily go back to it.

But Whenever I right Click on Root and Choose "Branch" Then I get an error that "The Bracnh Already Exists". I would like to name the new Branch "Release 2.0" or Something. But I cant Branch out my current Solution.

Creating New Folder option is Disabled.

[image]

Why is it **disabled**? I have full access to TFS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't branch from the team project root. Reorganize everything to be in a trunk folder (TFVC convention is `main`, but you can call it whatever you want), and branch off of that.

For what it's worth, branches shouldn't be infinitely branching -- you should branch off of a trunk to do development, then merge back in when development is done. There are numerous reasons why this is the case, but I suggest doing some reading on TFVC branching strategies to find one that's appropriate for your organization.

Comment: Could you please point me to a direction on how to create a TRUNK? that means I have to delete my entire Repo and start over?

Comment: Create a folder, then move the folders into it. Look at the right-click context menu and it should be pretty clear.

Comment: please look at  my Edit...Option is greyed out.

Comment: You're at the team project collection root, not the team project root.

Comment: Got it...Should I move "Build Process Templates" Folder into "main" as well?

Comment: That's up to you. Are you using XAML build, and if so, do you want to version your build process templates alongside the application? If the answer to both is "yes", then yes. If the answer to either is "no", then no.